# A parallel plate capacitor is insulated in a vacuum. How long will the charge hold?

Tags: capacitor

I've been researching parallel plate capacitors but couldn't find many experiments on how long a sealed parallel plate capacitor could possibly hold its charge and why.

To experiment, I ordered a 5 cfm vacuum generator w/chamber and plan on putting a copper parallel plate capacitor inside it at around 30 Hg. The plates have an area of 0.049 m², are about 1 mm thick, and about 7 mm apart. After charging it to, say, 15 V and disconnecting the leads, I'm wondering how long the charge will hold and why.

Any thoughts what'll happen? Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you using for any solid insulators? (hint, PTFE would be good). What are you using to measure the voltage? (hint, nothing would be best, with only an occasional connection to a high impedance meter) (or check out Rob Pease, femto-amp amplifiers).

Comment: How close are you to Chornobyl? Windscale? Fukushima? the stratosphere?

Comment: Is that meant to be 30 mm Hg (which would about 4 kPa)?

Comment: If you instead got a sheet of very thin Mylar/polypropylene film and sandwiched that between your plates tightly, you'll get orders of magnitude more capacitance, which will ease measurement.

Comment: PTFE works down to fA current range, then sapphire insulators should be used. Leak causes will include: light due to photoeffect, residual gas conductivity (very low, usually hydrogen and little water at UHV), ionizing radiation which creates conductive tracks in insulators and residual gas and also causes photoeffect. At such experiment i can only imagine good old mechanical electrometer, dynamometer or resonant capacitor.

Comment: It's about 30 Hg. Pretty much the max for the unit.

Comment: @HelloCthulhu, what does "It's about 30 Hg," mean? Are you stating the vacuum bellow ambient pressure? If so, that is not a true "vacuum" capacitor. Consider the *pressure* in a vacuum tube (valve),  far less than 1/10,000 Tor,, achieved using mechanical rotary pumps backing an oil diffusion or turbomolecular pump, and *then* a "getter" to absorb trace gases. See https://hackaday.com/2014/11/21/artisanal-vacuum-tubes-hackaday-shows-you-how/

Comment: The connectors for the external leads will leak charge.

Comment: 30″Hg is regarded as the maximum vacuum level available at sea level.   You need the log scale in torr to estimate breakdown voltage, using Paschens Law and with contamination measure  the particle count per cu.in. to estimate the ionic charge flow rate to estimate the electric field excitation of current to self-discharge. If you get all the particles to stick to the electrode, then it is surface leakage  or creepage not the vacuum., So it depends how many molecules of dust you have

Comment: 30 mm Hg would be a very poor vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

The leakage between the plates is essentially zero. You can calculate using the resistivity of air and the volume between the plates. By reducing the air pressure, the resistivity will increase.

The primary leakage path is along the surface of the of the vacuum container, both the inner surface and the outer surface. If the container is conductive then the insulated contacts will form additional capacitance with the one under test.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdKAsH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How long it will hold charge is determined by the choice an cleanliness of the insulating materials.

Of course, the voltmeter (electrometer) will also add R,L and C that may be the main source of leakage.

Looks like a fun experiment. The [physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) may have some suggestions.